# For differentiable function where $f'(0)=a$ and $f'(1)=b$ we have that for all $c\in(a,b)$ there exists a $y$ such that $f'(y)=c$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

So what I'm trying to prove: Assume a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $f'(0)=a$ and $f'(1)=b$. Prove that for any $c\in(a,b)$ there exists a $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(t)=c$

My first attempt was using the MVT and basically showing that there must exist such a point $y$ for $c=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ and then using this point to construct more mean values but I didn't know how to go from there or how to formalize that to show it must be true for all $c\in(a,b)$. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you apply the intermediate value theorem to f'? I guess that would require knowing f' is continuous.

Comment: Yeah the question specifies that we cannot assume f' is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you are trying to prove is called Darboux's theorem. It says derivatives have the intermediate value property.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29

The proof is on the page too.